# Django 1.11: URL function in template not working as expected

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I've created 2 test apps, test1 and test2, and added the same functions in the views and same entries in the url files. The problem is that it does not matter which app you access, the same link, appname/link, is shown as the href.

Does not matter if I access http://127.0.0.1:8000/test1 or http://127.0.0.1/test2, the link will always be "[Test Link](/test2/testapp/)"

Using the syntax url 'appname:link' does work, and sending an extra parameter to the html template to use the app name does work, but how can it be addressed only to use url 'link'

Project urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.views import generic
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^test1/', include('test1.urls')),
    url(r'^test2/', include('test2.urls')),
]
```

test1 url:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'testapp/', views.testapp, name='testapp'),

]
```

test2 url:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'testapp/', views.testapp, name='testapp'),


]
```

test1 views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'testme.html')

def testapp(request):
    return render(request, 'testme.html')
```

test2 views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'testme.html')

def testapp(request):
    return render(request, 'testme.html')
```

testme.html:

```
<a href = {% url 'testapp' %}>Test Link</a>
```

Is there perhaps a setting that can be set to only use url 'linkname' instead of using url 'appname:linkname'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by using middleware, goal was to use multiple apps and 1 template.

class getname(object):
    def **init**(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

```
def __call__(self, request):
    return self.get_response(request)

def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    request.view_full_name = ".".join((view_func.__module__, view_func.__name__))
    view_app_name_temp = request.view_full_name.split('.')
    request.view_app_name = view_app_name_temp[0]
```

On the template, change href link to the following:
href='/{{request.view_app_name}}/register'

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 urls with the name testapp.

change test2 urls to (or provide an app name)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index2'),
    url(r'testapp/', views.testapp, name='testapp2'),
]
```

Also, add quotes in your template

```
<a href ="{% url 'testapp' %}">Test Link</a>
```

Comment: Changed the code as suggested, but still the same issue.

Comment: Then I've misunderstood what you're trying to achieve. I've reread your post and cannot work out your goal

Answer (score 0):

you are using the same template for the `test1` and `test2`

first create 2 templates `test1` and `test2`

test1 `views.py`

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,'test1.html')
```

test1 `urls.py`

```
url(r'^$',views.index, name='test1'),
```

test1 template `test1.html`

```
<a href = {% url 'test1' %}>Test 1 Link</a>
```

test2 `views.py`

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'test2.html')
```

test2 `urls.py`

```
url(r'^$',views.index, name='test2'),
```

test2 template `test2.html`

```
<a href = {% url 'test2' %}>Test 2 Link</a>
```

project `urls.py`

```
path('test1/',include('test1.urls')),
path('test2/', include('test1.urls'))
```